# Apache Camel runtime error in DefaultLanguageResolver when using SimpleLanguage

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, exception, apache-camel

I am seeing this exception in my Tomcat server log when a simple language expression is being evaluated in a Camel route:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resolving language: simple detected type conflict: Not a Language implementation. Found: org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleLanguage
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultLanguageResolver.resolveLanguage(DefaultLanguageResolver.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.resolveLanguage(DefaultCamelContext.java:941)
at org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder.createExpression(SimpleBuilder.java:73)
at org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder.evaluate(SimpleBuilder.java:69)
at org.apache.camel.builder.ProcessorBuilder$4.process(ProcessorBuilder.java:96)
at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AsyncProcessorTypeConverter$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorTypeConverter.java:50)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:69)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:171)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:318)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:209)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:305)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:116)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:79)
at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:102)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:69)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:104)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:85)
at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:121)
at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:58)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is an example Camel route from the application that I'm including for completeness. You can see the `<camel:simple>` expression a few lines down:

```
    <camel:route id="com.acme.doStuffRoute"
        autoStartup="false">
        <camel:from
            uri="spring-ws:rootqname:{namepace}doStuff?endpointMapping=#com.acme.EndpointMapping" />
        <camel:setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_QUERY">
            <camel:simple>certainProperty=${ref:certainProperty}</camel:simple>
        </camel:setHeader>
        <camel:setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <camel:constant>POST</camel:constant>
        </camel:setHeader>
        <camel:policy ref="com.acme.Administrators">
            <camel:to uri="validator:WebService.xsd"/>
            <camel:to
                uri="xslt:/xslt/do-stuff-request.xsl?transformerFactory=transformerFactory&amp;uriResolver=uriResolver"
                pattern="InOut" />
            <camel:to ref="com.acme.ToLogging" />
            <camel:transform>
                <method bean="msgTransform" method="encrypt" />
            </camel:transform>
            <to uri="ref:doMoreStuffEndpoint" />
            <transform>
                <method bean="msgTransform" method="decrypt" />
            </transform>
            <camel:to ref="com.acme.FromLogging" />
            <to
                uri="xslt:/xslt/do-stuff-request.xsl?transformerFactory=transformerFactory&amp;uriResolver=uriResolver" />
            <camel:process
                ref="com.acme.MetricsProcessor" />
        </camel:policy>
    </camel:route>
```

The following jar files live inside the web application:

- camel-core-2.8.1.jar
- camel-http-2.8.1.jar
- camel-http4-2.8.1.jar
- camel-jaxb-2.8.1.jar
- camel-jms-2.8.1.jar
- camel-mail-2.8.1.jar
- camel-mina-2.8.1.jar
- camel-spring-2.8.1.jar
- camel-spring-security-2.8.1.jar
- camel-spring-ws-2.8.1.jar
- camel-stream-2.8.1.jar

I am using:

- JRE 8 update 45
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.62
- Windows Server 2008

Here is the excerpt from DefaultLanguageResolver in camel-core-2.8.1 where this exception occurs:

```
Class type = null;
    try {
        type = findLanguage(name, context);
    } catch (NoFactoryAvailableException e) {
        // ignore
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid URI, no Language registered for scheme: " + name, e);
    }

    if (type != null) {
        if (Language.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return (Language)context.getInjector().newInstance(type);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Resolving language: " + name + " detected type conflict: Not a Language implementation. Found: " + type.getName());
        }
    } else {
        // no specific language found then try fallback
        return noSpecificLanguageFound(name, context);
    }
```

The exception occurs on about 4 out of 5 machines with the same environment. Previously, the exception would disappear after performing a fresh install of all the software (Tomcat, Java, my webapp, etc.) but that no longer fixes it.

Sometimes the routes will run error-free after a fresh install, but then the exception starts occurring indefinitely after a reboot of the Tomcat server for the first time after install.

The error specifically means that the SimpleLanguage class is not assignable to the Language class. However, SimpleLanguage implements Language. I know that `isAssignableFrom` is a native Java method, so it's possible that the Camel version is out of sync with the Java version, but that doesn't explain why the issue happens on some machines and not others.

If it is possible to evaluate those simple expressions using another Expression language besides Simple, I'm open to that being the answer as well if examples can be provided.

EDIT: The camel jars listed above actually exist within two different webapps within my Tomcat. If I remove one of the camel-core jars from one of the webapps, I no longer get this exception and the route works fine. However I then get a ClassNotFoundException for a different class within camel-core for a different Camel route.